# Problems with oci_connect ORA-12541: TNS:no listener

Tags: php, oracle, php-extension

Yo guys. I have the following snippet:

```
$conn = oci_connect('user', 'pass', '(DESCRIPTION=
     (ADDRESS_LIST=
       (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
         (HOST=myhost.net)(PORT=1521)
       )
     )
     (CONNECT_DATA=
         (SERVER = DEDICATED)
         (SERVICE_NAME = MYSERVICE)
     )
 )');
```

That is giving me the following error: `oci_connect: ORA-12541: TNS:no listener`

That's the first time I try to connect to a oracle database. What am I doing wrong? I'm on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your TNS Listener service is running? You can check it by typing services.msc in the run dialogue box and you'll get a list of services running. If you do a quick lookup for Oracle, you will find TNS Listener. I am assuming your TNS entries are correct.

Comment: Note that you need to check services on `myhost.net`, _not_ on your client machine.

Comment: So... I don't have access to the host, but other people are connecting and querying normally in Java. It seems like a PHP problem, I don't know how to proceed =/ Maybe I installed/configured something wrong? Instant Client etc...

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with same error to connect oracle DB with codeigniter and finally after 2 days found some solution:

**Note: This steps worked for me in Wamp server - windows 10**

1. First download instant client from oracle offical website and extract it into some folder https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/downloads.html
2. Update environment variable `PATH` with instant client path i.e D:\php\instantclient_21_3
3. Edit your `php.ini` and uncomment `extension=php_oci8_12c.dll`
4. Restart your Wamp server

Comment: Useful info and thanks for sharing, but to avoid confusing other readers, it is not related in any way to the question's connection error.

Comment: @ChristopherJones its related to this `oci_connect ORA-12541: TNS:no listener` error so thats why shared here, hopefully it will be helpful to other.

Comment: It's not related at all - but your effort is appreciated.  The original poster had already successfully completed the steps (or equivalent) that you posted and was having a problem with the connection string or the database itself.  I pointed it out so other readers didn't waste time reinstalling the software if they hit this error.